# Many API calls in componentDidMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, apexcharts

My API returns sales data on a monthly basis, I am trying to display the last two years of data in an apex chart in react. I am trying to call the API many times for each month and format the data into something apex can display

```
componentDidMount() {
        var data = [];
        var categories = [];
        var maxYear = moment(new Date()).format("YYYY");
        for (var y = 2018; y <= maxYear; y++) {
            for (var m = 1; m < 13; m++) {
                axios.get(axios.get('http://localhost:8080/sales/lead/' + y + '/' + m))
                    .then(res => {
                        const value = res.data.lead_time;
                        data.push(value);
                        categories.push(m +" "+ y);

                    })
            }
        }
        console.log(data);
        console.log(categories);
        this.setState({
            series: [{
                data: data
            }],
            options: {
                xaxis: {
                    categories: categories
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

Where I console.log the outputs nothing is returned however. I assume I need to somehow await the return value of the get request on each loop however I'm not sure how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is null because the `console.log(data);` gets executed before your `.then(...)` clause.

I suggest you to read more about [Scope/Scoping in JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope), [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), [Callback functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function) and [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function), for those are very imporant in JS.

This should work:

## Using Promises:

```
componentDidMount() {
  var data = [];
  var promises = [];
  var categories = [];
  var maxYear = moment(new Date()).format("YYYY");

  for (var y = 2018; y <= maxYear; y++) {
    for (var m = 1; m < 13; m++) {
      promises.push(axios.get'http://localhost:8080/sales/lead/' + y + '/' + m))
    }
  }

  Promise.all(promises)
    .then(results => {
      results.forEach(res => {
        const value = res.data.lead_time;
        data.push(value);
        categories.push(m + " " + y);

        console.log(data);
        console.log(categories);
      });
    })

  this.setState({
    series: [{
      data: data
    }],
    options: {
      xaxis: {
        categories: categories
      }
    }
  })
}
```

## Using async/await:

```
async componentDidMount() {
  var data = [];
  var categories = [];
  var maxYear = moment(new Date()).format("YYYY");
  for (var y = 2018; y <= maxYear; y++) {
    for (var m = 1; m < 13; m++) {

      var res = await axios.get('http://localhost:8080/sales/lead/' + y + '/' + m)
      const value = res.data.lead_time;
      data.push(value);
      categories.push(m + " " + y);

      console.log(data);
      console.log(categories);

    }
  }

  this.setState({
    series: [{
      data: data
    }],
    options: {
      xaxis: {
        categories: categories
      }
    }
  })
}
```